# Is it fine to use road bikes for daily commute?

Tags: road-bike

Is it fine to use the montra unplugged 1.1 2015 as a daily commute bike?

[image]

Aluminium Alloy frame
Kenda Koncept tyres, 700x23c

Comment: You can commute on any bike.

Some bikes being more practical and suited than others.
What is the commuting distance?
What kinds of roads will you commuting on - broken / gravel / smooth etc?

Comment: Yeah.... A bit broken but otherwise smooth

Comment: Certainly looks like a reasonable commuting bike to me, so long as you can somehow carry whatever gear you need, and so long as the posture suites your style.  What would make you think it's not OK for commuting?

Comment: Why the down-votes? I can see how someone could wonder if a road bike is okay for commuting, given that there are bikes billed specifically as "commuters". @user162862 , one thing to consider is that this bike does not appear to have attachment points for racks or mud guards. Whether or not that is a disadvantage is up to you.

Comment: @renesis I -1'd because the OP could clearly have answered his own question by looking at several other posts on this site. He's essentially asking for product recommendation

Comment: @renesis because the question is so ridiculously over-specific and there's not enough information to even guess at an answer. The asker has clearly put zero effort into even thinking about their question, let alone trying to find an answer. There are already many, many answers to this question both here and more generally online. I also downvoted the various guesses at answers to what the question might be. No-one has even mentioned the snow problem, in winter Estonia sees 50cm of snow at times and this bike can't even be modified to cope with that.

Comment: Fair enough, & good point that the op didn't mention where he/she was from. Estonia? I assumed the bike was Indian?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't see a single reason why not.
I am commuting on road bikes since the times of Noah (ok, a bit later) and only being happy for the decision. Used MTB before and it was not as fun as road bike is on roads.

There are some interesting issues, such as rugged bottoms of the trousers of your dress suit if you don't clamp them while commuting, also some funny looks from the strangers but otherwise it is all only positive.

Commuter bike is more exposed to the external elements such as sun and rain so be ready to maintain some rust and molten tires (been there). With the rust it is easy - keep your grease on, especially after the rainy days. With the molten tires under the sun it is a bit more tricky, but I have found out empirically that Michelin tires melt like butter while, say, Contis stay hard for a longer time.

Comment: Re: oily pants... Roll your trouser cuffs up, or tuck them into your sock, or wear a velcro/snap band to restrain the cloth.   I wear cycling pants on long rides, but don't bother when its just to work.  As for the funny looks, they're jealous/envious of you.

Answer (score 2):

I made the decision to ride starting this year in Feb (yes, Toronto in February) but it was then or never. I have never looked back. Only things that I wondered before I started (and what took me longer was):

- The distance of course as someone already mentioned...
- What you would wear while riding (linked to the next point)
- Given my work attire, what would be the best bike to ride on and/or how do I dress into work attire on reaching work.
- What all you normally carry (assuming you travel via public transport currently or drive) and how to do the same seamlessly via bike (ie pannier)
- Parking at work: Do you have indoor parking or you would park outside
- Lastly (that comes to mind right now) is what would you do in rainy or harsh weather

These are things I considered when I decided to ride and bought myself a dutch commuter with chain guards and mud flaps etc which made my life much much easier. I cant view a pic of your bike but the decision to ride is inherently linked to what you currently have or what you would need if you do decide to ride as your primary mode of transport to work.

Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

I do both - my road bike is a lightweight lean machine with no mudguards so its fast but terrible in the wet, so dry days only.

My wet-day bike is a rigid MTB with full mudguards (fenders) and much better rim brakes.  The MTB also has a more upfright seating position so its easier to look around, and puts my head a little higher.

Road bikes commute fine, but its easy to go fast and get to work all hot and sweaty.  So change of clothes, and you may need a shower there too.

My MTB has a carrier rack and trailer towball as well, so if I'm moving stuff the MTB is the only choice.  Backpacks are okay for small light things, but they make you sweat more, and they do make injuries from accidents worse.

Comment: How do backpacks make injuries worse?

Comment: @lazyrabbit  Anything unyeilding that is by your body could act as a fulcrum or focus point for impact forces.  Imagine doing a gymnastic rolly-polly, vs doing the same with a loaded backpack on.  Michael Schumaker's skiing accident was exacerbated by his gopro mounting, acting as a concentrator for impact forces that should have been spread out and dissipated by his helmet.